# Where to find a list of all the operable exploration / mining companies conducting operations in Canada

Tags: equities, data, database, data-mining

Looking to create a database firstly of all the exploration / mining companies conducting research in Canada. TSX and TSX-V have very nice spreadsheets with several filtering operations, which is very nice. NASDAQ has a downloaded txt file of all companies, some-what difficult because you don't know which are under which sector (technology, cannabis, mining, etc.).

If I wanted to achieve my goal, would I simply go through the 16 major list of stock exchanges and continue in this manner?

Also, are the 'majority' of exploration / mining companies publicly traded? Is it possible that they are private? If so, how would I then access the information?